# Как определить основание системы счисления числа?

Tags: математика, информатика, системы-счисления

118924 в 10 системе счисления = 350214 в х системе счисления, как найти х? если можно то попродобнее

Comment: Нашел аналогичный вопрос на SO, но переводить лень: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600100/how-to-determine-base-of-a-number/2602285#2602285](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600100/how-to-determine-base-of-a-number/2602285#2602285)

Comment: чет я там не понял не чего! ... откуда читать начать?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Это ж всё брутфорс, это ж несерьезно :)

На самом деле, конечно, перебор здесь вполне подходит, и можно дать ему границы сразу — по количеству цифр, по максимальной цифре. Но есть же и аналитический метод.

**350214<sub>*х*</sub> = 118924<sub>10</sub>**

Это означает, что

**3*x*<sup>5</sup> + 5*x*<sup>4</sup> + 0*x*<sup>3</sup> + 2*x*<sup>2</sup> + 1*x* + 4 = 118924<sub>10</sub>**

или

**3*x*<sup>5</sup> + 5*x*<sup>4</sup> + 2*x*<sup>2</sup> + *x* – 118920 = 0**

Классический многочлен пятой степени. И теперь нужно просто решить полиномиальное уравнение. По основной теореме алгебры у него будет пять комплексных корней, нас, правда, интересует только действительный, хорошо бы положительный, и хорошо бы целый :)

Из [теоремы Абеля-Руффини](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8) известно, что аналитически мы такое уравнение не решим в общем случае, но я бы даже и пробовать не стал: на то придуманы численные методы, которых всяких есть многатыщ — выбрать можно по вкусу, начиная хоть с метода товарища Ньютона. Решаем, и получаем:

***x* = 8**

Хорошо и красиво. Ну можете еще добить преподавателя комплексными корнями, сказав, что это же число записывается точно так же в системе счисления с основанием **(-7.07949 - 4.865*i*)** :)

Comment: получается только перебор? очень жалко что другого метода нет...))а
"Это ж всё брутфорс, это ж несерьезно :)" - это как понять? чет не вкурил к чему это! ))) ну ладно +

Comment: Я к тому, что другие ответы были про перебор. И это правильно, вообще-то, потому как перебрать десяток оснований легче, чем решить полином пятой степени.

Comment: Не брутфорс, можно сделать бинарный поиск по X! :)

Answer (score 4):

Что бы перевести число с какой то системы счисления с основой Х в десятичную, нужно делать так:
1) начальная сумма 0
2) текущая цифра - самая первая
3) текущую сумму умножаем на основу Х
4) добавляем текущую цифру к сумме.
5) если справа ещё есть цифры - к пункту 3 иначе выход
Так как вручную проверять все это лень, пишется небольшая программа, к примеру на питоне

```
def r(x):
    return (((((3 * x + 5) * x + 0) * x + 2) * x + 1) * x + 4)

for i in range(6,10):
    print i, r(i)
```

Начинаем с 6, так как все цифры в заданном числе точно меньше 6 и это будет минимально возможная основа.
А верхняя 9, так как "визуально" число в системе счисления Х больше его записи в десятичной форме.

и конечный ответ - 8.

Comment: капец я тупой, не понял

Comment: можете на примере обьяснить?

Comment: посмотрите на это
 (((((3 * x + 5) * x + 0) * x + 2) * x + 1) * x + 4)
не угадываете свое число?

Answer (score 4):

Топовый ответ прекрасен. Осталось только уточнить решение.

Итак, получено уравнение
**3*x<sup>5</sup> + 5*x<sup>4</sup> + 2*x<sup>2</sup> + *x* – 118920 = 0**.
И есть следующие соображения к его решению:

1. **x** - основание системы счисления, т.е. целое число.
2. В записи числа встречается цифра 5, т.е. **x>5**.
3. Число в искомой системе счисления выглядит больше нежели в десятичной, т.е. **x<10**.
4. Все целочисленные решения степенного уравнения являются делителями его свободного члена, и после проверки остаётся только **x=8**.

Подстановка в уравнение показывает, что это ответ.

Comment: Третий пункт в списке — очень изящно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй перебором. Начни с 6-ти разрядной системы счисления

Comment: ну это в тупую, как бы понятно))) а как это сделать правильно! чтоб наверняка ,без перебора...

Comment: Тогда смотри на максимально число. В 6-ти разрядной, не может быть числа больше 6-ти, в 8-ми - числа больше 8-ми и т.д.
Это максимально точный способ, другой сейчас поищу

Comment: логично, что 9. Потому что на кодирование одной цифры в 8 системе нужно 3 бита (двоичный логарифм 8 = 3). поэтому и 3*3 = 9.
Тут есть одна заковырка. Если было бы сказано не 576, а к примеру 177, то тогда как раз 7 бит.
Поэтому правильнее брать двоичный логарифм от 576, который равен 8 с копейками (а для получения ответа нужно округлять в большую сторону).

Comment: 3 бита (двоичный логарифм 8 = 3) - вот это было интересно)
но, двоичный логарифм от 576 будет равень 9 с копейками а значит ответ 10))) 2^9=512, и 9 бит просто не хватит для 576 по это теории)))

Comment: 576 в восьмеричной системе, а не десятичной. В десятичной это все лишь 382.

Answer (score 0):

"Оптимизированный" перебор мог бы выглядеть так (Java):

```
public static int getNotation(int decBased, int[] xBased) {
    outer: for (int base = 6; ; base++) { // как определить нижнюю границу вы уже знаете
        int tmp = decBased;
        int i = xBased.length - 1;
        while (tmp != 0) {
            int integral = tmp / base;
            int part = tmp % base;

            if (xBased[i] == part) {
                tmp = integral;
                i--;
            }
            else {
                continue outer; // отбрасываем основание, как только остаток от деления не равен соответствующей цифре чисда
            }
        }
        return base;
    }
}
```

Набросал по-быстрому и грязновато, но, наверно, суть понятна. Алгоритм основан на [переводе числа в Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B4_.D0.B8.D0.B7_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F).